# Curved space-time and metric tensor

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, curvature

I'm studying about curved spaces and I read that a manifold is flat if there a coordinate system such that the metric tensor is constant everywhere.

Then I also read that when the space-time tensor is the Minkowski tensor that is constant everywhere, so why is space-time curved?

Comment: The Minkowski metric tensor is the metric tensor of Minkowski spacetime. In general the metric tensor is a Lorentzian metric tensor which is a solution to the Einstein Field Equations. So it is not true, in general, that the metric of spacetime is the Minkowski metric.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Space-time can be curved, does not mean that it is always curved. By substituting Minkowski metric in general relativity one will arrive at the equations of special theory of relativity. That is why it is called *special* theory of relativity. When there is no space-time curvature we are dealing with special relativity.

However the metric need not necessarily be the Minkowski metric. There are a lot of other metrics that describe spacetime like the Schwartzchild metric, Kerr metric, Newman metric, FLRW metric, deSitter metric and so on. Minkowski metric is the simplest of them since it deals with flat space-time.

Comment: A slight correction... "By substituting Minkowski metric in general relativity one will arrive at the equations of special theory of relativity" will not work since any mass will necessarily generate curvature.  You will get a manifold of zero curvature but a violation of the field equations.

Comment: @ggcg Yes that is right. But what I meant was substituting it in the action $$S=-m\int{ds}$$ and not the field equations.

Answer (score 1):

The metric tensor is defined by the matrix $e_i.e_j$. Where $e_i$ and $e_j$ are the basis vector at a point. For a curved space these basis vector differs at each point. In special relativity we consider a small part of curved space which assumes to be flat. So we deal with a space in which basis vector doesn't change (flat space). The metric tensor defined for the flat space  is called Minkowski metric which is constant.

Space time is curved. But in special relativity we consider space as flat. Thus the metric for space time is constant.

Answer (score 1):

Note that there can be a flat manifold, but a metric tensor which is not constant. Best example is the metric tensor of polar coordinates in 2-dimensional space as one of the simplest examples.

$$ds^2 = dr^2 + r^2 d\phi^2$$

So the metric tensor component $g_{22}=r^2$ which changes with radial distance from the origin. To check if a manifold is flat or not the Riemann curvature tensor (it is a 4-tensor) has to be non-zero, for polar coordinates  this tensor is zero.  The curvature tensor can be computed from the first and second derivatives of the metric tensor (see definition in WK). From this we can at least conclude that having non-constant metric tensor components is a necessary condition for manifold to be curved, but this condition is not sufficient.
The Minkowski metric describes 4-dimensional space-time in special relativity which is flat. This can be checked by the computation of the Riemann curvature tensor which turns out to be zero.

Comment: Flat is there is a globally constant metric.  Your example does not contradict the OP.

Comment: @ggcg: You are right, indeed my argumentation is not answering the question straightforward, but nevertheless given in 2 last sentences. I wanted to show that the ultimate criterion for a distinction between a curved space and a flat space is the curvature tensor.

Answer (score 1):

A curved space-time is not described by the Minkowski metric, only flat space-time is described with this device.  In curved space-time every local neighborhood can be expressed using Minkowski, i.e. space is locally flat.  The same is true of Riemannian diff geom.  Manifolds are locally Euclidean.  This is how manifolds are technically defined in mathematics.